# Fonts in SWF do not work in IE 8

Tags: javascript, flash, internet-explorer-8, svg, font-face

I have an SVG in an HTML page. Old browsers like IE 8 do not support SVG, so I load Google's [SVG Web](http://code.google.com/p/svgweb) library for Flash fallback. If the browser is legacy, SVG Web turns the SVG into a phantom object and replicates its functionality in a SWF.

This works, except in IE 8 if the SVG has a text element with a font-family attribute. IE 8 ignores the font-family in the SWF.

[Example](http://svgweb.s3.amazonaws.com/ie8-fonts.html)

I load the @font-face in a stylesheet:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'MyriadPro-BoldIt';
    src: url('myriadpro-boldit-webfont.eot');
    src: url('myriadpro-boldit-webfont.woff') format('woff'), 
         url('myriadpro-boldit-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'), 
         url('myriadpro-boldit-webfont.svg#webfontyYDLSfQE') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

And apply that font-family to a text element in the SVG:

```
<script type="image/svg+xml">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="720" height="120" version="1.1">
        <text x="190" y="80" id="font-test" font-size="44.06" fill="#94dfe3"
        font-family="MyriadPro-BoldIt">MyriadPro-BoldIt</text>
    </svg>
</script>
```

The text looks great regardless of what client I use to view the page. *Except IE 8* which renders it in the default IE 8 font.

The text also looks perfect when I instruct SVG Web to *force Flash* on a modern browser.

Suggestions?

Comment: Take a look at this, http://www.codingforums.com/showthread.php?t=226003

Comment: @Daniel - Good idea. I have now tried it both ways, with the smiley and without. Sadly it does not resolve the issue but I will leave it in for good measure going forward. Thank you!